# Possible keylogger? How to remove?

Tags: malware

I'm tailing var/log/sys.log and I keep getting this message:

```
Jul 13 23:43:52 mac[redacted lol] syslogagent[19960]: Authentication String htt[space added]p://logsviewer.com/membermac/livedesk/arewelive.php?username=

Jul 13 23:43:53 mac[...] syslogagent[19960]: {
```

every 25 seconds or so.

Sometimes it'll include a string of numbers such as:

```
Jul 13 17:50:41 mac[...] syslogagent[19960]: Authentication String htt[space added]p://logsviewer.com/membermac/livedesk/arewelive.php?username=

Jul 13 17:50:41 mac[...] syslogagent[19960]: 2147483647

Jul 13 17:50:42 mac[...] syslogagent[19960]: {
```

And as I was writing this it changed (for the first time since I caught it about 9 hours ago today, although after the tail logfile turned over and I restarted it) its process ID number to [21174]

After some intensive googling I found out that this URL roughly matches that which occurs in the SniperSpy spyware program.

First of all, am I correct. Second of all, I ran Sophos and nothing came up. Third, is it even functionally installed because the message makes it seem like it maybe didn't get fully installed. Fourth, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge possibility that you have a spyware.
Please check [this link](https://www.clamxav.com/BB/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3660&sid=15000a3e2a280d7759d98bb01e3d71d2&start=15).

> It is an Application named "SysLogAgent" which is hidden in your home
>   folder along with files to launch it at startup and when you log in
>   and none of them were detected as infected.

**How to remove (Spyware.SniperSpy.B - Removal)?**
Please check [this link](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2010-081606-4034-99&tabid=3).

Comment: @soren After removing Spyware.SniperSpy.B check the app(s) you installed on 13th of July and/or the website(s) you visited immediately before you got infected.